# Right Spherical Triangle with rational sides in Spherical Trigonometry

Tags: spherical-geometry

What formula relates rational sides and hypotenuse  in spherical geometry?

I obtained an example quite by chance:

$$ \cos  \frac{5}{18} \cos  \frac{1}{3} = \cos  \frac{31}{72}   $$

with radius of sphere $72$, sides $(20,24)$ and "hypotenuse" $31.$

.. like we have flat Euclidean sides/hypotenuse geometry using rationals $(m^2-n^2,2mn, m^2+n^2 ).$

Comment: $\cos\left(\frac5{18}\right)\cos\left(\frac13\right)=0.9087340898$ while $\cos\left(\frac{31}{72}\right)=0.9087340145$

Comment: @robjohn Rational  solution  is not possible due to the  transcendental nature of the relation,right ?

Comment: I don't see an easy proof that there are not any rational solutions, but there probably are not any easily generated families of solutions as there are for Pythagorean triangles.